# Does My Domain secure our Enhanced Domain before enabling Enhanced Domains?

Tags: mydomain, enhanced-domains

If we have `ExampleCo` setup as our My Domain and we go to enable Enhanced Domains, is there any possibility that `ExampleCo` is not available as an Enhanced Domain? That is, when we click that "Check Availability" button is it possible for some other company to have already claimed our `ExampleCo` domain as their Enhanced Domain, or does having it already set as My Domain secure it for us?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced domains don’t change your My Domain login URL in production unless you also change your My Domain name or suffix. When you enable enhanced domains in a sandbox, the word “sandbox” is added to all My Domain URLs, including the org’s My Domain
login URL: *MyDomainName--*SandboxName.sandbox.my.salesforce.com**. Similarly, the URL for your Lightning pages also changes in a sandbox, but not in production.

Salesforce deployed this feature in all orgs with Summer ’23. Enhanced domains are also deployed by default in new, refreshed, and cloned sandboxes.
Until this feature is enforced in Winter ’24, you can disable enhanced domains.

Here are some example URL formats for a production org with enhanced domains.

Production: MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com,
Sandbox: MyDomainName--SandboxName.sandbox.my.salesforce.com

Check more details of [Salesforce Enhanced Domains FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393816&type=1) and [Considerations for Enhanced Domains](https://Considerations%20for%20Enhanced%20Domains).